# Can a very fast centrifuge affect the path of a light beam?

Tags: visible-light, reference-frames, acceleration, centrifugal-force

I am thinking the answer is "no" since you can't see time dilation (I have read) in a centrifuge. But why would a light beam not be bent by what is felt like gravity to someone inside the centrifuge?

Answer (score 1):

Take for example an ordinary roundabout in a fairground. Imagine a light beam going from one place to another, both on the edge of the roundabout as it rotates. If we take the point of view of someone sitting on the edge of the roundabout, who adopts a reference frame (an accelerating one) in which they are permanently at rest, then to them the direction towards the central axis is "up". So they consider that the light beam I just described first goes "up" and then comes back "down".

Answer (score 1):

There is a philosophy of science dimension here that must be adressed.

When you do some local experiment you need to assess what the scope of the results is. Is it valid to extrapolate the result, to *everywhere* and *always*?

There is the following obvious rule: a line of reasoning is valid only if all relevant information is taken into consideration. Later in this answer I will call this rule.

When the centrifuge is spinning then a local measurement setup will find the light propagating along a path that is curvilinear with respect to the centrifuge frame.

If the centrifuge setup is pulling 1 G of acceleration then the curvilinear path will be consistent with light being bent by 1 G of gravitational pull.

Because of the kind of physics we're dealing with here that result does not extrapolate to everywhere. You assess how far to expand your perspective. A natural step up is the Earth as a whole. You know the rotation rate of the centrifuge with respect to the Earth. You take the propagation of the light with respect to the Earth; the centrifuge does not bend the light.

Then again, we know the Earth itself is a rotating platform, so depending on how sensitive our measurement setup is we may have to take the Earth rotation rate into account too.

The point is: it's alway fundamental to expand your perspective to whatever scale is necessary. How far you need to scale up is a judgement call.

Some people may propose:
For the purpose of the thought experiment: when I disregard that I know the centrifuge is rotating, can I draw the conclusion that the beam of light is being bent?

Well, disregarding some of your knowledge defeats the purpose of doing science. You may object: it's a *thought experiment*, you get all kinds of leeway in a thought experient. You do get leeway, but not when it comes to logic. It is *science* only if you follow the rules of reasoning:

A conclusion is valid only if *all* relevant information is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There is time dilation effect for a circular movement. Suppose an observer at rest with the center of the centrifuge, and located somewhere close to its radius.

For every time $T$ corresponding to the period of the rotation, his clock is compared with a rotating clock. As an inertial frame, if $T$ is the time of his clock, the period for the rotating clock is smaller.

The light will bent, but only for an observer in the centrifuge. It is different from the effect of gravity (the displaced position of stars close to the sun during an eclipse for example) that affect observers far from its gravitational field.